# How to subtract Time Column from DateTime Column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time, subtraction

I have `Crea_Date` column which is a `DateTime` Column. I want to subtract the value in the `IST` column from `crea_date` Column and return a new column with the `DateTime` Value in it. My sample data is like this:

```
States  crea_date               IST
AB      2014-12-30 15:01:00.000 12:30:00.0000000
AK      2014-12-29 16:32:00.000 10:30:00.0000000
AZ      2014-12-18 16:07:00.000 11:30:00.0000000
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using SQL- Server, MySQL, Oracle etc? Is IST a datetime column too?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti, I am using SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `IST` is an integer number of seconds:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, -IST, crea_date)
FROM yourTable
```

If `IST` is of the `TIME` type:

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, IST, '00:00:00'), crea_date)
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: when trying your method I am receiving the error:
'Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Operand data type time is invalid for minus operator.'

Comment: Edited my answer adding the `TIME` type case. It wasn't clear in the first version of your question.

Comment: Your answer serves my purpose. Just one more SMALL Help Needed! How to have the data in the New Column as '2014-12-31 03:31 PM'?

Comment: The result for your first row is `2014-12-30 02:31:00.000` so I don't know if you are asking to convert the resulting datetime to the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi AM` format string or rather do some adjustments?

Comment: @TheDProgrammer dates do not have formats, they are binary values. Formats apply only when dates are converted to strings by an application eg for display

Answer (score 5):

As strange as it might seem, you *can* add/subtract `datetime` values and it seems it's "normal" behavior.

Internally, datetime values are stored as the offset from `1/1/1900`. If I add `22/1/2015` and `1/1/2015` I get `22/1/2130` because the second value is actually `115` years after `1900`.

When you cast a `time` value to `datetime` only the time component is copied and the date component is set to `1/1/1900`. In effect, you have an interval equal to your original time value.

This way I can subtract `10:30` hours from a specific datetime:

```
declare @d datetime='2014-11-04 12:51:00', @t time='10:30:00'
select @d -cast(@t as datetime)

//-----------------------
//2014-11-04 02:21:00.000
```

This behavior isn't an implementation quirk - it is explicitly permitted only for the `datetime` type. All other datetime types (eg datetime2, datetimeoffset) return the error `Operand data type datetimeoffset is invalid for subtract operator`.

Comment: Indeed, `SELECT crea_date - cast(IST as datetime) FROM yourTable` is more elegant than my solution.

Comment: And totally unexpected. **IF ONLY** SQL Server had proper interval support!

Comment: I've always stored intervals as plain `INT` number of seconds. It's only now that I learned that SQL Server 2008 has introduced the `TIME` type.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below if IST is a character based column.

```
SELECT  
Crea_Date, IST,
dateadd(hh,cast(substring(IST,1,2) as int),  
    dateadd(mi, cast(substring(IST, 4,2) as int), 
             dateadd(s, cast(substring(IST,7,2 ) as int), crea_date)
             )) Final_Date
from [Yourtable]
```

You will get the added date in `Final_Date` column.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention 'IST' column is 'Time' Column with the data in the format '12:30:00.0000000'...thanks

Answer (score 0):

With slight modification in @0xF Answer I found the final Solution:

```
convert(varchar(10),
DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', IST), crea_date), 101) + right(convert(varchar(32
DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', IST), crea_date),100),8)
```

Comment: Swap '00:00:00' with IST if you want the time _subtracted_ from `crea_date`.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.